# Angular 1 UI-Router - HTML5 Mode param URL to always end with a forward slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5mode

I've got a page that has a base URL of /foo/ and have set up my state to expect a param.

So, if the user hits /foo/user1/, **user1** is the param.

Is it possible to watch for both types of urls? For example, can I declare /foo/user1/ and /foo/user1 (notice, there's no forward slash) in the same state or do I need to create another state to specifically watch for the trailing slash?

Currently, it can be one or the other, but not both. Is that an accurate statement, or am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're after – https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/frequently-asked-questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using latest version of `ui-router` add this in your config block  `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)` but for older versions of `ui-router` add this code

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.url();

    // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
    if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        return path.replace('?', '/?');
    }

    return path + '/';
});
```

you should checkout their [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/frequently-asked-questions) area, there is a dedicated section for [trailing slash](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/frequently-asked-questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes)

Comment: That rule was exactly what I was looking for. I'm using the latest version, but $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false) wasn't doing the behavior I was looking for. Thanks for providing both options, wish I could vote this answer twice!